# Unity: How to inject configuration and already registered instance

Tags: c#, unity-container

```
    public class Job1:IJob
    {
        public Job(MyService service)
        {
        }
    }

    public class Job2:IJob
    {
        public Job(MyService service,int hours)
        {
        }
    }


    public static IUnityContainer ConfigureUnityContainer()
    {
        UnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterType<MyService, MyService>();
        container.RegisterType<IJob, Job1>("Job1");  
        container.RegisterType<IJob, Job2>("Job2", new InjectionConstructor(Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Hours"])));  
        return container;
    }
```

I have two clases `Job1` and `Job2` derived from `IJob` interface. See the constructor implementation above

The `Job2` Constructor takes 2 parameters. The value of the second parameter is comming from config file. I am passing that value while registering `Job2`.
However for first parameter `MyService`, i was hoping Unity will automatically pass `MyService` instance to the constructor since its already register. But when execute i get error

> MyNameSpace.Job2 does not have a constructor that takes the parameters
>   (Int32).

Note that, Unity is able to pass instance of `MyService` to `Job1`

Comment: I think that this is a foundation issue. You should check the documentation -> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648449.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add first parameter - type of service:

```
container.RegisterType<IJob, Job2>("Job2", new InjectionConstructor(typeof(MyService), Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Hours"])));
```

Comment: I never knew you could pass a type in and it would resolve it in a InjectionConstructor. Cool!

Comment: InjectionConstructor tells Unity which one to use for object creation. In your example it tries to use constructor with one parameter

Comment: Umm, it's not my question

Comment: @ScottChamberlain haha, sorry :) log day

Comment: Look at LP13's profile. He has not visited the website since Jun 29 at 18:55. I think he abandoned the question for now.

Comment: @Backs I am back and accepted your answer. Sorry for delayed response :)